# Script to move a row to different columns in new sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to move a Google Sheets row from one sheet to another based on the value of a cell. What I'm now trying to accomplish is cherry picking column placement.

For example 'Client' in Column one gets moved from Leads to Opportunities in the corresponding column one, and 'Client Phone' in Column Two gets moved from leads to column five in opportunities, and 'Source' in column three just gets skipped all together, then repeat with following columns.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I have for moving rows.

```
function onEdit() {
// moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column

var sheetNameToWatch = "Leads";

var columnNumberToWatch = 9;
var valueToWatch = "Opportunity";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Opportunities";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
  sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An "object literal" can be used to make user settings that will determine the source and destination.

Example:

```
function onEdit() {
  var mySettings,thisSheet;//Define variables without assigning a value

  // USER INPUT
  mySettings = {//make settings here
    "targetSheetOne":{//First sheet to get data
      "columnToColumnMap":{//source column to be put in target column
        "column1":"column5",//source column1 will be copied to target column5
        "column2":"column2",
        "column3":"column3"
      }
    }
  }

  // END OF USER INPUT

  for (key1 in mySettings) {//Loop through all target sheets in settings
    thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(key1);

    innerObject = mySettings[key1];

    for (key2 in innerObject) {
      //Write column data to correct column

    }

  }
}
```